# Non-Existence of Probability Measure Support for Non-Separable Space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, separable-spaces

Suppose that we have a probability measure $P$ on space $(S,\mathcal{B}(S))$. There is the statement that says, if $S$ is separable then the support of $P$ always exists. Whereas in the case where $S$ is not separable the support of $P$ may not exist.

The support of the probability measure $P$ is defined as

$$supp(P)= \cap\left \{ \bar{A}\in \mathcal{B}(S)|P (\bar{A}^{c})=0 \right \}$$

Could someone elaborate an example of such a case, where we have a non-separable space with a support that doesn't exist??

Answer (score 1):

A standard example is the so-called Dieudonné measure on $[0,\omega_1)$, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal. A complete description of this measure can be found in [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/dema-2018-0010/pdf) or in Example 4.33 [p. 92] in [Wise & Hall, *Counterexamples in Probability & Real Analysis*](https://books.google.nl/books?id=CPRCD_XLVIwC&pg=PA95&dq=Dieudonn%C3%A9+measure&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4xaX3x7PzAhVQtKQKHfpiDIwQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=Dieudonn%C3%A9%20measure&f=false).